# Multiple plots on the Same axes in Matlab GUI Radio Buttons

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a matlab GUI with several radio buttons , each button when pressed will generate a graph to be plotted on an axes placed in the GUI . I want all these plots to remain on the same axes. I used " Hold on" what happens is that when i press a 2nd radio button the previous graph is pushed upwards instead of holding it's position ! meaning that the previous plot is distorted . please help D:

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: CST as in coast ? anyway i just figured it out and was coming here to just delete this thing , thanks a lot anyway :D